# Why isn't module.css recognizing or using my CSS media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, hubspot

I am working on a Hubspot project and have never encountered this issue before. My module.html file looks like this:

```
  <div class="header_text" style="text-align: center; font-size: 36px; padding-top: 130px; font-family: Lustria; font-weight: semi-bold; color: #05254C;">
  {% inline_text field="header_text" value="{{ module.header_text }}" %}
</div>
<div class="header_body_text" style="width: 50%; font-family: Arimo; font-size: 18px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 15px; color: #05254C; padding-bottom: 50px;">
  {% inline_rich_text field="header_body_text" value="{{ module.header_body_text }}" %}
</div>

<!--
This secion houses each video in its own column, with the "video_titles" div also housing the video title underneath.
-->
<div class="video_titles">
  <div class="row" style="width: 60%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0px;">
     <div class="column" style="background-color: #153357; width: 45%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; max-width: 550px;">
       {% if module.test.player_id %}
    {% set max_width = module.test.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test.max_width : module.test.width %}
    {% set max_height = module.test.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test.max_height : module.test.height %}
    {% widget_block video_player "embed_player"
        overrideable=False,
        type='scriptV4',
        hide_playlist=True,
        viral_sharing=False,
        embed_button=False,
        full_width={{ module.test.size_type == 'auto_full_width' }},
        width="{{ max_width }}",
        height="{{ max_height }}",
        player_id="{{ module.test.player_id }}"
    %}
        {% widget_attribute "conversion_asset" %}
            {{ module.test.conversion_asset|tojson|safe }}
        {% end_widget_attribute %}
    {% end_widget_block %}
{% endif %}
         <p style="color: white;  font-family: Lustria; font-size: 36px; border: 2px solid #638869; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
            Athletics
         </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: #153357; width: 45%; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: -10px; float: left; max-width: 550px;">
      {% if module.test_2.player_id %}
    {% set max_width = module.test_2.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_2.max_width : module.test_2.width %}
    {% set max_height = module.test_2.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_2.max_height : module.test_2.height %}
    {% widget_block video_player "embed_player"
        overrideable=False,
        type='scriptV4',
        hide_playlist=True,
        viral_sharing=False,
        embed_button=False,
        full_width={{ module.test_2.size_type == 'auto_full_width' }},
        width="{{ max_width }}",
        height="{{ max_height }}",
        player_id="{{ module.test_2.player_id }}"
    %}
        {% widget_attribute "conversion_asset" %}
            {{ module.test_2.conversion_asset|tojson|safe }}
        {% end_widget_attribute %}
    {% end_widget_block %}
{% endif %}
      <p style="color: white;  font-family: Lustria; font-size: 36px; border: 2px solid #638869; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        STEM
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="video_titles" style="padding-top: 50px;">
  <div class="row" style="width: 60%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0px;">
     <div class="column" style="background-color: #153357; width: 45%; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: -10px; float: left; max-width: 550px;">
       {% if module.test_3.player_id %}
    {% set max_width = module.test_3.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_3.max_width : module.test_3.width %}
    {% set max_height = module.test_3.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_3.max_height : module.test_3.height %}
    {% widget_block video_player "embed_player"
        overrideable=False,
        type='scriptV4',
        hide_playlist=True,
        viral_sharing=False,
        embed_button=False,
        full_width={{ module.test_3.size_type == 'auto_full_width' }},
        width="{{ max_width }}",
        height="{{ max_height }}",
        player_id="{{ module.test_3.player_id }}"
    %}
        {% widget_attribute "conversion_asset" %}
            {{ module.test_3.conversion_asset|tojson|safe }}
        {% end_widget_attribute %}
    {% end_widget_block %}
{% endif %}
       <p style="color: white;  font-family: Lustria; font-size: 30px; border: 2px solid #638869; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
         Humanities
       </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: #153357; width: 45%; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: -10px; float: left; max-width: 550px;">
      {% if module.test_2.player_id %}
    {% set max_width = module.test_2.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_2.max_width : module.test_2.width %}
    {% set max_height = module.test_2.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_2.max_height : module.test_2.height %}
    {% widget_block video_player "embed_player"
        overrideable=False,
        type='scriptV4',
        hide_playlist=True,
        viral_sharing=False,
        embed_button=False,
        full_width={{ module.test_2.size_type == 'auto_full_width' }},
        width="{{ max_width }}",
        height="{{ max_height }}",
        player_id="{{ module.test_2.player_id }}"
    %}
        {% widget_attribute "conversion_asset" %}
            {{ module.test_2.conversion_asset|tojson|safe }}
        {% end_widget_attribute %}
    {% end_widget_block %}
{% endif %}
      <p style="color: white;  font-family: Lustria; font-size: 30px; border: 2px solid #638869; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        Performing Arts
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="video_titles" style="padding-top: 50px;">
  <div class="row" style="width: 60%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0px;">
     <div class="column" style="background-color: #153357; width: 45%; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: -10px; float: left; max-width: 550px;">
       {% if module.test_5.player_id %}
    {% set max_width = module.test_5.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_5.max_width : module.test_5.width %}
    {% set max_height = module.test_5.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_5.max_height : module.test_5.height %}
    {% widget_block video_player "embed_player"
        overrideable=False,
        type='scriptV4',
        hide_playlist=True,
        viral_sharing=False,
        embed_button=False,
        full_width={{ module.test_5.size_type == 'auto_full_width' }},
        width="{{ max_width }}",
        height="{{ max_height }}",
        player_id="{{ module.test_5.player_id }}"
    %}
        {% widget_attribute "conversion_asset" %}
            {{ module.test_5.conversion_asset|tojson|safe }}
        {% end_widget_attribute %}
    {% end_widget_block %}
{% endif %}
       <p style="color: white;  font-family: Lustria; font-size: 30px; border: 2px solid #638869; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
         Visual Arts
       </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color: #153357; width: 45%; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: -10px; float: left; max-width: 550px;">
      {% if module.test_6.player_id %}
    {% set max_width = module.test_6.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_6.max_width : module.test_6.width %}
    {% set max_height = module.test_6.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' ? module.test_6.max_height : module.test_6.height %}
    {% widget_block video_player "embed_player"
        overrideable=False,
        type='scriptV4',
        hide_playlist=True,
        viral_sharing=False,
        embed_button=False,
        full_width={{ module.test_6.size_type == 'auto_full_width' }},
        width="{{ max_width }}",
        height="{{ max_height }}",
        player_id="{{ module.test_6.player_id }}"
    %}
        {% widget_attribute "conversion_asset" %}
            {{ module.test_6.conversion_asset|tojson|safe }}
        {% end_widget_attribute %}
    {% end_widget_block %}
{% endif %}
      <p style="color: white;  font-family: Lustria; font-size: 30px; border: 2px solid #638869; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        Girls Leadership
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

and my module.css file looks like this:

```
header_text {
  font-family: "Lustria"; 
};

header_body {
  font-family: "Arimo"; 
};

/* Responsive layout - makes the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other & fits text to screen size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
  .column {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
};
```

Hubspot seems to be ignoring my media queries... and everything I have tried is not getting it to work. Am I just dumb and missing something?